# Importing module in other package causes error

Tags: python

I have the following project structure:

```
project/
  app1/
    __init__.py
    views.py
    helper.py
  app2/
    __init.py
    file2.py
```

`app1/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)    
from app1 import views
```

In `app1.helper`, I can do `from app1 import app` and it works. If I try to do the same import in `app2.file2`, I get `ImportError: No module named flask_app`. I tried `sys.path.append`/`insert` but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `from ..app1 import app`? It should work.

Comment: No it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i had set the PYTHONPATH variable to module i want to import it works fine